# Bootstrap. Get icon next to li navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I am I'm trying to place the "Home" icon next to the word "Home" and place it in the same grey block, I am doing this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="main.php">Home</a><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></i></li>
```

I have tried to place it in several places without success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), it's not very clear what you want or what you need. But for starters, try to place the `<i>` element inside the `<a>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not inside the anchor tag ?

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="main.php">Home<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></i></a>
</li>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/urnb1wha/

If you want the Home icon towards the extreme right use `pull-right` class to the glyphicon like this

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="main.php">Home<i class='pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-home'></i></a>
</li>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/urnb1wha/1/